# Firestore.getInstance(): how to use?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, singleton

Firebase Firestore provides the `getInstance()` method, which opens a socket (only one, at any time of execution of the app) and instanciates the Firestore client.

I would want to query and store data, using or not listeners (to get realtime updates, etc.). If I call `getInstance` as soon as I need to query or store, or if I store this instance in a static class when my app starts and then use this static class attribute as soon as I need to query or store: these 2 cases are technically the same. Because Google uses singleton pattern (`getInstance()`).

But am I missing something? Is it actually safe to store this instance as a static class attribute, and use it when I need it? And is it really safe to call `getInstance` whenever I need it? **To be more explicit: between 2 calls to `getInstance()` (or between 2 accesses to the static class attribute), *i.e.:* between 2 points of execution time, is there any risk to loose network connection, socket connection, realtime listeners (snapshots) connection, etc. ?**

If yes: How to handle these problem(s)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would want to query and store data, using or not listeners (to get realtime updates, etc.)

There is no way to get data or even get realtime updates without using a listener. Everything in Cloud Firestore is about listeners.

> if I store this instance in a static class when my app starts and then use this static class attribute as soon as I need to query or store

Do not place Android context classes in static fields. Static reference to FirebaseFirestore which has field context pointing to Context will lead to a memory leak.

A static field will leak contexts. Non-static inner classes have an implicit reference to their outer class. If that outer class is for example a Fragment or Activity, then this reference means that the long-running handler/loader/task will hold a reference to the activity which prevents it from getting garbage collected.

So instead of storing it as a static variable call `getInstance()` whenever is needed. Or a more convenient solution would to use dependency injection. [Dagger](https://github.com/google/dagger) can help you solve that.

> And is it really safe to call getInstance whenever I need it?

Yes it is.

> between 2 accesses to the static class attribute), i.e.: between 2 points of execution time, is there any risk to loose network connection, socket connection, realtime listeners (snapshots) connection, etc. ?

Please see explanation above.

Comment: I just have a little question: you say everything is about listeners. According to the documentation, only snapshots are. But the method `get()` doesn't set up listeners no? Since it's not "real-time".

Comment: Even if you are using a `get()` call, the listener is added but is removed right after that. You cannot get something from the database unless you are using a listener.

Comment: How do you know that a `Context` attribute is inside `FirebaseFirestore`? It's not specified here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore :)

Comment: This is the error about Android Studio conplains when using this practice. [There](https://www.google.com/search?q=Do+not+place+Android+context+classes+in+static+fields) are lots of posts regarding this topic.

Comment: So @AlexMamo if I have lots of fragments needing a Firestore getInstance, I should add to all of these Fragments a new `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();` instead of having on the MainActivity an instance to use for them all?

Comment: @E.Akio There is no problem in using `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`, it's a Singleton, so it will always create a single instance.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Alex Mamo's answer, and avoid repeating `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` everywhere, I declared a static method called `db` which returns the result of the getInstance :

```
public static FirebaseFirestore db(){
    return FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
};
```

Then I use it like that :

```
db().collection(...)
```